# Angular2 jspm dependency issue

Tags: angular, jspm

After switching to jspm for Angular2 package management (instead of using the script tag), I have a handful that are not loading.  It seems it's looking for them in the root: http://localhost:55707 rather than in the jspm location specified in config.js.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:55707/zone.js(…)
http://localhost:55707/reflect-metadata.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:55707/es6-shim.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:55707/rxjs/add/operator/map.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Config.js

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "typescript",
  paths: {
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*"
  },

  map: {
    "angular2": "npm:angular2@2.0.0-beta.1",
    "typescript": "npm:typescript@1.7.5",
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0": {
      "assert": "npm:assert@1.3.0"
    }, 
    "npm:angular2@2.0.0-beta.1": {
      "crypto": "github:jspm/nodelibs-crypto@0.1.0",
      "es6-promise": "npm:es6-promise@3.0.2",
      "es6-shim": "npm:es6-shim@0.33.13",
      "process": "github:jspm/nodelibs-process@0.1.2",
      "reflect-metadata": "npm:reflect-metadata@0.1.2",
      "rxjs": "npm:rxjs@5.0.0-beta.0",
      "zone.js": "npm:zone.js@0.5.10"
    },
    // -- more mappings
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing `zone.js` directly by your package you need an additional `map` entry for it.

```
    "angular2": "npm:angular2@2.0.0-beta.1",
    "typescript": "npm:typescript@1.7.5",
    "zone.js": "npm:zone.js@0.5.10", //<-- Add this line
    "github:jspm/nodelibs-assert@0.1.0": {
```

It looks like you also need an entries for a few other packages too.  Add them in the same fashion if your package relies on them directly.  If they are used by a dependency you may need to specify [package overrides](https://github.com/jspm/registry/wiki/Configuring-Packages-for-jspm) to make them available to your dependencies.